# Setting null to optional parameters using TypeORM and MySQL database

Tags: mysql, express, typeorm, typegraphql

I'm trying to create a graphql mutation to edit the account details of my app users. An account have fields for gender and birthday (optional fields). In my InputType I have:

```
@InputType()
export class UserEditAccountDetailsInput {
    @Field()
    email: string;
    @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
    birthday?: string | null
    @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
    gender?: string | null
}
```

And for the ObjectType:

```
@Field({ nullable: true })
@Column({ default: null })
gender?: string

@Field({ nullable: true })
@Column({ default: null, type: 'date' })
birthday?: string
```

I've tried in this way:

```
@Field({ nullable: true })
@Column({ default: null, type: 'date' })
birthday?: string | null
```

but I receive this error:

> NoExplicitTypeError: Unable to infer GraphQL type from TypeScript
> reflection system. You need to provide explicit type for 'birthday' of
> 'User' class.

I've also tried to specify the type for birthday and gender like this:

```
@Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
@Column({ default: null, type: 'date' })
birthday?: string
```

but the issue wasn't fixed.

If I don't specify that " | null" on my ObjectType, it seems to work fine, but I have this TypeScript issue:

> Types of property 'gender' are incompatible.
> Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type '(() => string) | QueryDeepPartialEntity<string | undefined>'.

Do you have any ideas about what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented the same scenario but I didn't get an error. Maybe there is a problem with graphql versions. If you update the versions with the versions I will post below, you can solve the problem:

```json
"graphql": "^15.3.0"
"type-graphql": "^1.1.1"
"@types/graphql": "^14.5.0"
"typescript": "^4.7.4"
```

By the way, there may also be an error with tscongif.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2019",
    "lib": ["es6", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack"
  ]
}
```